# Return object from passed class parameter

Tags: java, generics

In my program I have an abstract class A and some other classes which extends from A. Here is a little excerpt from my code:

```
public abstract class A {
    public A(int[] values) {
        // ...
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    public B(int[] values) {
        super(values);
        // setup other things
    }
}

// some more classes like B
```

Now I have a class which reads out some integer values from a file and writes them in an array. This class only have static methods and I want to return an object from a passed class. With this code I can give the class B to the method but how can I create and return an object of the class with I have called the method? I tried wi this:

```
B obj = Reader.readFromFile(path, B.class);

public class Reader {
    public static *** readFromFile(String path, Class<? extends A> c) {
        // read out the file and store values in an array
        // how can I create an object of the parameter c and return it from here?
    }
}
```

> I do not want to make the whole class generic. Any ideas how to do
>   this or is this not possible in Java?

Comment: have you tried the return type Class<? extends A> ?

Comment: you can use reflection to get constructor of class and then invoke that constructor with contents of files you read. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/constructors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution would be that you instantiate the object before calling the method, and pass that instance to the method. Then, you could use a setter to pass the values:

```
public static void readFromFile(String path, A c) {
    c.setValues(...);
}
```

`B` should then provide a nullary constructor.

If you really need to instantiate the object within the method, you could still use reflection :

```
public static void readFromFile(String path, Class<? extends A> c) {
    int[] values = ...;
    Constructor<T> constructor = c.getConstructor(int[].class);
    T instance = constructor.newInstance(values);
}
```

Comment: The `T` is unnecessary in both cases. The first declaration can be simplified to `public static void readFromFile(String path, A c)`. The second method can be simplified to `public static void readFromFile(String path, Class<? extends A> c) {
    int[] values = ...;
    Constructor<? extends A> constructor = c.getConstructor(int[].class);
    A instance = constructor.newInstance(values);
}`

Comment: actually I liked your "return T-based" answer more. I believe author want to use created instances later on ( see `***` in question). Currently the "instance" is lost.

Answer (score 3):

You can create instance of provided class via reflection. In your case you need to get a proper constructor via [c.getConstructor(int[].class)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) and then create new object calling [newInstance(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance(java.lang.Object...)) method of that constructor

Comment: Thank you for that. But how do I have to set the return type of the class then?